# Find all occurrences of a multi-line string between two defined tags in Python with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do something a bit unexpected. I want to parse a Python code in which some specific comment lines define a block of text or of code that I would like to extract. For this example, I will be using two types of tags, one for code, one for text description.

```
#c
print ("this is the tag I used for code I want to find")
#-c

#d
"""This is the tag I used for a description I want to find"""
#-d
```

Why am I tagging my code this way? Well, that's for another question. More details in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876777/documenting-and-detailing-a-single-script-based-on-the-comments-inside) if you are interested.

Now, I have been trying to catch those tags with regular expression, and as it's my first time using regex, I obviously didn't succeed... Here is my current attempt:

```
file = 'script.py'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read() 
text = read_python_script(file)

code_blocks = re.compile(r'(?s)(?<=#c\n)(.*\n)(?=#-c)')
desc_blocks = re.compile(r'(?s)(?<=#d\n)(.*\n)(?=#-d)')

code = re.findall(code_blocks, text)
desc = re.findall(desc_blocks, text)
```

Here is an example of a script I would like to parse:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Title: blablabla
Author: Mathieu

Description: Report the some measurements
"""

import time
import uuid

from database.model import TestLimit, TestResult
from util import log

#d
"""
blablabla some description
which might be multiline
"""
#-d
# Constants
#c
CONSTANT_1 = 10     # Unit
CONSTANT_2 = 2      # Unit
#-c

class Foo(Fp):
    def __init__(self, #some parameters):
        # some init

    def _run(self, #some parameters):
        #%% Section Title 1
        #%%% Sub section Title 1
        #c
        code I would like to catch
        can be multiple liens
        #-c

        
        with something.open():
            #%%% Sub section title 2
            #d
            """some description I want to catch"""
            #-d
            
            #c
            some more code I want to catch
            #-c
```

At the moment, I am getting only the first occurrence and I don't know why...

**EDIT:** As mentioned, I should change my expression to a lazy format:

```
r'(?s)(?<=#c\n)(.*?)(?=\n#-c)'
```

This doesn't completely solve the problem as I am still only catching the first occurence.

Comment: `r'(?s)(?<=#c\n)(.*?)(?=\n#-c)'` - use lazy quantifier

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the lazy approach description. Indeed I missed that part, but it doesn't fully fix my problem. I am still only matching the first occurrence because the other one are present at another indentation level and don't get caught by the `re.findall()`.

Comment: Then just add a pattern to match the horizontal whitespaces. See https://regex101.com/r/7HuNyS/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Still, why is the current expression not working? Why can it not catch a string which starts somewhere in the middle of the line, e.g; after several horizontal whitespaces. The fact that there are `\t` characters somewhere shouldn't affect the fact that there is somewhere in the middle a string enclosed between the `#c` and `#-c` tags; and this string should be detected and returned.

Comment: Because `\n#-c` matches `#-c` only straight after a newline. `re.findall(r'(?sm)#c\n(.*?)\n[^\S\r\n]*#-c', text)` will do, no need of lookarounds, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7HuNyS/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are taking the example of the end of the line with `#-c`... Thank you, for the regex101 demo, I will look into the different tags to understand what they are doing, especially the `sm` instead of `s` and the `[...]`.

Comment: You actually do not need `m` modifier in the latest comment. There is no `^`, nor `$` in the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?s)#c\n(.*?)\n[^\S\r\n]*#-c', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7HuNyS/4).

There are two things here:

- The lazy matching `.*?` pattern
- `[^\S\r\n]*` matching any 0 or more horizontal whitespaces that must be used before `#-c` since there may be some indentation before the symbols.

**Details**

- `(?s)` - inline `re.DOTALL` modifier
- `#c` -  a literal string
- `\n` - a newline
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\n` - a newline
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `#-c` - a literal string.